# How to disable "Completion time:..." in SQL Server Messages window

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms

Every query I run in SSMS append the annoying message: "Completion time:...".

How can I disable that text?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In SSMS 18.3, they added the option to turn off the completion time.

**Tools** > **Options** > **Query Execution** > **SQL Server** > **Advanced**.

Uncheck the **Show Completion Time** checkbox.

Start a new query window and execute something... 
No completion time after query finishes. Yay!

Answer (score 17):

The completion time message was added in SSMS 18.2

https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/07/25/sql-server-management-studio-18-2-is-now-generally-available/

I don't believe there is a way to turn it off